# How to add wishlist data to trailData without overwriting existing data?

Tags: php, laravel, api, e-commerce, lumen

I'm new to PHP and I'm building API for wishlist, for both guest users and logged-in users in Laravel Lumen. Here I'm using TrailManagerService as session manager
It saves data as

```
- for logged in users
   Array
(
[trail_id] => 4b19bd9d-f2da-431b-8aba-d181d7eca736
[inception_time] => 1599813465
[last_used] => 1600762156
[customer_id] => 106210
[customer_data.customer_id] => 106210
[customer_data.firstname] => XXXX
[customer_data.lastname] => YYYY
[customer_data.gender] => Male
[customer_data.dob] => 1999-10-19
[customer_data.email] => xx@yy.com
[customer_data.mobile] => 2245436547
[customer_data.referral_code] => HRI11489

-for guest users
 Array
(
[trail_id] => 8b7e6931-6ad3-48a0-af61-4caaab85cf20
[inception_time] => 1600761357
[last_used] => 1600761391
```

I want to add wishlist items to trailData and save it to DB if user does login and then emptytraildata after it get saved to DB. Also, if user doesnt login wishlist data should be saved in trailData for current session.

Code for WishlistControllerService

```
   <?php

    namespace App\Http\Services\v1\Products;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Services\SOA\TrailManagerService;
    use App\Repositories\WishlistRepository;
    
    class WishlistControllerService
    {
        public function __construct(WishlistRepository $wishlistRepository)
        {
            $this->wishlistRepository = $wishlistRepository;
        }
    
        public function showList(Request $request){
            $trailData = TrailManagerService::getAllTrailData('customer_id');
            $trailCustomerId = TrailManagerService::getTrailData('customer_id');
            $headerCustomerId = (int) $request->header('X-Customer-ID', 0);
    
            $responseData = [];
            $trailCustomerId = $trailData['customer_id'] ?? 0;
            print_r($trailData);exit;
            if($trailCustomerId === $headerCustomerId) {
                // print_r("hi");exit;
    
                $wishlistData = $this->wishlistRepository->getWishlist($trailCustomerId);
    
                $responseData = [
                    'identifier' => 'wishlist',
                    'data' => [ 
                        'list' => $wishlistData
                    ]
                ];
            } else if($trailCustomerId === 0) {
                // print_r("bye");exit;
                // $tempWishlistItem = [
                //  // 'guestUserID'        => $, 
                //  'productID'         => $request->input('product_id'), 
                //  'sizeID'            => $trailData['size_id'],
                //  'productQuantity'   => $request->input('quantity'), 
                //  'shippingPin'       => $request->input('postal_code'), 
                //  'shippingCity'      => $request->input('city_name'), 
                // ];
    
                $responseData = [
                    'identifier' => '',
                    'data' => [ 
                        'list' => []
                    ]
                ];
            } else {
                // print_r("why");exit;
                $responseData = [
                    'status' => 403,
                    'message' => 'Access Forbidden'
                ];
            }
    
            return $responseData;
        }
    public function store($request, $productId){
        $trailData = TrailManagerService::getAllTrailData();
        $responseData = [];
        $headerCustomerId = (int) $request->header('X-Customer-ID', 0);

        $trailCustomerId = $trailData['customer_id'] ?? 0;

        $tempWishlistItem =
            [   
                // 'siteUserID`'        => $customerId ?? $trailCustomerId,
                'productID'         => $productId, 
                'sizeID'            => $request->input('size_id'),
                'productQuantity'   => $request->input('quantity'), 
                'currency'          => strtoupper($request->input('currencyCode')), 
            ];
        $tempData[] =
        array_push($trailData, $tempWishlistItem);
        
        TrailManagerService::setTrailData($trailData);
            
        print_r($trailData);exit;


        // if($trailCustomerId === $customerId) {


            $wId = $this->wishlistRepository->create($wishlistModelData);
                    $responseData = ['data' => ['userWID' => $wId]]; 
            $wishlistModelData = [
                'siteUserID'        => $customerId, 
                'productID'         => $productId, 
                'sizeID'            => $request->input('size_id'),
                'productQuantity'   => $request->input('quantity'), 
                'currency'          => strtoupper($request->input('currencyCode')), 
            ];
            // print_r($wishlistModelData);exit;

            $wishlistItem = $this->wishlistRepository
                ->findWhere(['status' => 1, 'siteUserID' => $customerId, 'productID' => 
    $productId]);
            if(empty($wishlistItem[0]) === false) {
                $responseData = [   
                    'status' => 403,
                    'message' => 'Forbidden, Item already in Wishlist'
                ];

            } else {
                $wId = $this->wishlistRepository->create($wishlistModelData);
                    $responseData = ['data' => ['userWID' => $wId]];    
            }
            
        } else {
            // $tempWishlistData = [];
            $tempWishlistItem =
                [   
                    // 'siteUserID'     => $customerId ?? $trailCustomerId,
                    'productID'         => $productId, 
                    'sizeID'            => $request->input('size_id'),
                    'productQuantity'   => $request->input('quantity'), 
                    'currency'          => strtoupper($request->input('currencyCode')), 
                ];
            
                    $tempWishlistData = array_merge($trailData, [$tempWishlistItem]);
                    print_r($tempWishlistData);exit;
                    $trailDataTemp = TrailManagerService::setTrailData(

                    $tempWishlistData   
                );
                print_r($trailDataTemp);exit;
                
            if($customerId === $trailData['customerID']){
                
                foreach($tempWishlistData as $item) {
                    $wId = $this->wishlistRepository->create($wishlistModelData);
                    $responseData = ['data' => ['userWID' => $wId]];    
                }

                TrailManagerService::emptyTrailData();
            }

    
        
        return $responseData;
    }
```

I want to add wishlist items to trailData and save it to DB if user does login and then emptytraildata after it get saved to DB. Also, if user doesnt login wishlist data should be saved in trailData for current session.

Code for Wishlist Controller

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1\Products;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Services\v1\Products\WishlistControllerService;
    use Validator;
    use App\Helpers\Utilities;
    use App\Services\SOA\TrailManagerService;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    
    class WishlistController extends Controller
    {
        private $controllerService;
    
        public function __construct(WishlistControllerService $controllerService)
        {
            // $request = app(Request::class);
            // $customerId = $request->header('X-Customer-ID', 0);
            // TrailManagerService::authorize($customerId);
            
            $this->controllerService = $controllerService;
    
        }
    
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $responseData = $this->controllerService->showList($request);
            
            $httpStatus = $responseData['status'] ?? 200;
    
            return $this->response($responseData, $httpStatus);
        }
        
    
        public function store(Request $request, int $productId){
            $requestParams = $request->all();
            // $requestParams['productId'] = $request->header('product_id');
            
            $validator = Validator::make($requestParams,
                [
                    'product_id'    => 'integer',
                    'size_id'       => 'integer',
                    'quantity'      => 'required|integer|digits_between:1,2',
                    'currencyCode'  => 'required|string|in:INR,EUR,USD,AUD,CAD,SGD,HKD'
                ],
                [
                    'product_id.integer'=> 'Parameter product_id is mandatory',
                    'size_id.integer'   => 'Invalid value for parameter size_id',
                ],
            );
    
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $messages = $validator->errors();
                $responseData = Utilities::requestValiationResponse($messages);
            } else {
                // print_r($productId);exit;
                $responseData = $this->controllerService->store($request, $productId);
            }
            
            $httpStatus = $responseData['status'] ?? 200;
    
            return $this->response($responseData, $httpStatus);
        }
    
        public function remove(Request $request, int $productId)
        {
            $responseData = $this->controllerService->remove($request, $productId);
            
            $httpStatus = $responseData['status'] ?? 200;
    
            return $this->response($responseData, $httpStatus);
        }
    
    }
```

Code for Wishlist Repo

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Repositories;
    
    use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;
    use App\Models\MxUserWishlist;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use App\Helpers\Utilities;
    
    class WishlistRepository extends BaseRepository
    {
        /**
         * Specify Model class name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function model()
        {
            return MxUserWishlist::class;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param  int  $customerId
         * @return array
         */
        public function getWishlist($trailCustomerId): array
        {
            $wishlistData = [];
            
            $query = "SELECT W.userWID, W.siteUserID, W.productID,P.productTitle, PSI.imageName, 
                W.sizeID, S.sizeTitle, D.designerName,P.designerID, P.categoryID, 
                PS.productPrice, PS.discountPercent,PS.filterPrice,P.seoUri
                FROM  mx_user_wishlist W
                INNER JOIN mx_product P ON P.productID = W.productID 
                INNER JOIN mx_product_set PS ON (W.productID = PS.productID AND W.sizeID = PS.sizeID)
                INNER JOIN mx_product_set_images PSI ON PSI.productID = W.productID
                INNER JOIN mx_size S ON S.sizeID = W.sizeID  
                INNER JOIN mx_designer D ON P.designerID = D.designerID
                WHERE W.siteUserID = $trailCustomerId";
        
            $wishlistCollection = DB::select($query, ['siteUserID' => $trailCustomerId]);
            
            if(empty($wishlistCollection) === false) {
                foreach ($wishlistCollection as $key => $wishlist) { 
                    $productId = 0;
                    $productUrl = '';
                    $productUrl = '/products/'.$wishlist->seoUri.'/'.$wishlist->productID;
    
                    $wishlistItems = [
                        'id'                    => $wishlist->productID,
                        'name'                  => $wishlist->productTitle,
                        'image'                 => config('global.cdni_url').'/tr:w-317/uploads/product/'.$wishlist->imageName,
                        'product_url'           => $productUrl,
                        'sizes'                 => [
                                                    'id' => $wishlist->productID,
                                                    'name' => $wishlist->sizeTitle
                                                    ],
                        'designer_name'         => $wishlist->designerName,                
                        'category_id'           => $wishlist->categoryID,                
                        'mrp'                   => $wishlist->productPrice,
                        'discount_percentage'   => $wishlist->discountPercent,
                        'you_pay'               => $wishlist->filterPrice,
                    ];  
                }   
                return $wishlistItems;
            } else {
                $responseData = [];
                return $responseData;
            }
            // return $responseData;
        }
```